# when I adding bootstrap to my project, the <li> tag colors disorder and change to another color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

when I adding bootstrap  to my project, the -li- tag colors  disorder  and change to another color.
How i can control colors by adding bootstrap to my project also control colors when i hover?

```
<nav>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#section-1"><span>معرفی</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-2"><span>رویدادها</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-3"><span>فعالیت های هنری</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-4"><span> تولیدات</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-5"><span>فیلم </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-6"><span>نمایش </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-7"><span>بازیگری</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-8"><span>نوشتار</span></a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>


css:
nav>ul>li{
            /* width: 8%; */
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 1%;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 23px;
            color:white;**(doesn't work by adding bootstrap)**
           


        }
nav>ul>li:hover{
            background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
            color: black;**(doesn't work by adding bootstrap)**
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you can post a snippet of your css and html, but if I have to guess:

**1-** you might not be targeting the right or more specific element- to solve this make sure you give the element you want to target a class name in your html and use that class name in css (don't use the general li name, because the bootstrap styling will be prioritized ).

**2-** if you are using a framework or a library like angular, react, gatsby ..
make sure you import your css **after** you import bootstrap, it should look somethin like this:

```
import './bootstrap.min.css'
import './layout.css'
```

If you still can't target your element please share with us some more details.

Comment: hi guy my post edited please review that.

Comment: Houssein can you please include all your html and css, so we can see how you are importing bootstrap and css. or may be a link to your site if it's live.